# How to catch and fix the reason of WebView not showing web-content with JS

Tags: java, javafx, webview, ace-editor

I have simple `JavaFX` application with `WebView` element on form and I load web-content with `ace-editor` into that element.
In result on my PC form shows me content in the style of `ace-editor` but on pc of my colleague this JS style is not showing.
I'm looking for some way to catch the reason for that trouble.

I tried to check it on my laptop, home PC and work PC - it works with no troubles.
Also, I thought that console can show me some error but there are no errors.

I know only that trouble is independent of the platform (i checked it on Windows 10  and my colleague has the same windows - the difference only between antiviruses but if my colleague runs clear HTML with the same code it would work as expected - with styles).

There is a `initialize` procedure where I set content

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    wbView.getEngine().loadContent(content);
}
```

I can't put here full HTML of content. And I think it doesn't metter because on my PC it works anyway.

As result on my PC it looks like that:
[image: onMyPc]

On my colleague's PC (but should be like on mine):
[image: onColleaguePc]

upd#1
I tried to add this code.

```
public void initialize() {
    wbView.getEngine().loadContent(content);
    System.out.println("Errors from wbView: " + wbView.getEngine().onErrorProperty());

    System.out.println("worker error : " + wbView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getMessage());

    wbView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        System.out.println("load state: "+ newState);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

In result:

Errors from wbView: ObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine@13d4522, name: onError, value: null]
worker error : Loading
load state: SUCCEEDED

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all resources needed are loaded correctly?

Comment: Of cource. I ran the same `.jar` application in different PC

Comment: Does [`WebEngine.onError`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#onErrorProperty) or the [load worker's](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getLoadWorker()) `exception` property give any hint?

Comment: @Slaw, sorry for long pause. I have updated post. I put additional code to get worker message and load state. There are not errors again. May be i done something wrong?

Comment: And `onError` doesn't emit anything? I'm not terribly familiar with the web components of JavaFX, but maybe it outputs errors separate from those of a failed load worker.

Comment: As i showed at updated post part `onError` has `null` value in onErrorProperty

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that part. However, the `onError` property holds an `EventHandler` that gets _invoked_ (with a `WebErrorEvent`) if an error occurs. That said, the different event types of `WebErrorEvent` all seem to deal with the user data directory, so it might not be helpful in this case anyway.